# JavaDoc warn of possible NullPointerException

Tags: nullpointerexception, javadoc

I've written a method that returns the most likely LAN Interface on Android.  Since the user may not be connected to a LAN, it's possible for this method to return null.  How should I warn callers about this possibility in the JavaDoc?  I don't think I should use @throws since the method doesn't actually throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: `@return sometype|NULL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right way to do this would be in the return clause:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @return {@code null} if the user is not connected to a LAN, else the most
 * likely LAN interface.
 */
public LanInterface getMostLikelyInterface();
```

It would be the responsibility of the caller to know that this means not to use the returned value before a check.

Though you could use Guavas' `Optional` class instead:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @return Optional.absent if the user is not connected to a Lan interface,
 *    else the most likely one.
 */
public Optional<LanInterface> getMostLikelyInterface();
```

The users then would have to use `if(iface.isPresent())`, which is much more readable than `if(iface != null)`.